# Display the stored value in variable by flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I want to display the variable value using flask,
Here is the code which i have tried

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def get_values():
    v1 = 1
   return "v1"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I need to display the value of v1 that is 1 in the application.

Comment: Display how? Just as a `text/plain` response or something else?

Comment: just to display the value 1 which is stored in v1@Daniel Pryden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to serve a plain text response containing the string representation of the number in the `v1` variable, all you need is:

```
return str(v1)
```